# Spring Boot 2 - local css file not used for index page

Tags: html, css, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot 2 application.

The css files are stored under resources/static/css. These files are referenced in index, which is mapped in the controller.

But when index is initially loaded, there is no css formatting from my css files. Inspecting the elements show empty. At this point I have not logged in and received an Oauth2 token.

After logging in I then go to another page, the css formatting is applied. And returning to index shows formatting.

An example of code in html is

```
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href = "css/navigation.css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
    <link href = "css/demo.css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

Just to add, in my security configuration, I have

```
  http
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("user")
     .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/unpkg.com/**", "/cdn.jsdelivr.net","/error**","/*.js","/css/**")
     .permitAll()
     .anyRequest()
     .authenticated()
     .and()
     .csrf()
     .csrfTokenRepository(new CookieCsrfTokenRepository())
     .ignoringAntMatchers("/api/**");
```

So guess this is a security problem but the above looks correct. Though I guess it is not ...

Answer (score 0):

And the answer was order of the antMatchers.

```
  http
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/unpkg.com/**", "/cdn.jsdelivr.net","/error**","/*.js","/css/**")
     .permitAll()
     .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("user")
     .anyRequest()
     .authenticated()
     .and()
     .csrf()
     .csrfTokenRepository(new CookieCsrfTokenRepository())
     .ignoringAntMatchers("/api/**");
```